# How to match numbers to alphabets with period and space,

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

```
ToCharacterCode["ABCD...XYZ"] - 64
```

I know that I can make a list of alphabets in this way.

However, I need to assign `" "` and `"."` too.

Like `" "=27` and `"."=28`

For example `"I AM A BOY." = {9,27,1,13,27,1,27,2,15,25,28}`

Comment: maybe `ToCharacterCode["I AM A BOY."] - 64 /. {-32 -> 32, -18 -> 46}`?

Answer (score 4):

```
ToCharacterCode["I AM A BOY."] - 64 /. {-32 -> 32, -18 -> 46}
```

> {9, 32, 1, 13, 32, 1, 32, 2, 15, 25, 46}

where `" "` and `"."` are mapped to their respective character codes. If you wish to map `" "` to 27 and `"."` to 28, you can use

```
ToCharacterCode["I AM A BOY."] - 64 /. {-32 -> 27, -18 -> 28}
```

> {9, 27, 1, 13, 27, 1, 27, 2, 15, 25, 28}

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [`PositionIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html) and just build the string using `CharacterRange`:

```
Catenate@Lookup[
 PositionIndex[Characters[CharacterRange["A", "Z"] <> " ."]],
 Characters["I AM A BOY."]]
(* {9, 27, 1, 13, 27, 1, 27, 2, 15, 25, 28} *)
```